# Indirect formula referencing of formula in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a a Google sheet which have multiple tabs in them

I use formula to get the consolidated info from the known names of the tabs as shown below

```
=UNIQUE({Appliances!A2:B;'Base, Trim & Crown'!A2:B;'Bathroom Accessories'!A2:B;'Bathroom plumbing'!A2:B;Cabinetry!A2:B;Carpet!A2:B;Closets!A2:B;'Entry Door'!A2:B;'Exterior and Interior Stone'!A2:B;'Exterior Lighting and Fans'!A2:B;'Exterior Siding'!A2:B;Fireplaces!A2:B;'Garage Doors'!A2:B;Gutter!A2:B;'Interior Door'!A2:B;'Kitchen Plumbing'!A2:B;'Paint Color'!A2:B;'Patio Stone'!A2:B;Roofing!A2:B;Slab!A2:B;Staircase!A2:B;Tile!A2:B;'Timbers, Beams & Ceilings'!A2:B;'Windows & Multislides'!A2:B;'Wood Flooring'!A2:B})
```

Suppose if I add a new sheet tab, this formula need to be updated again, which is cumbersome for me. So I am thinking is it possible to have a range in MASTER sheet that lists all sheetnames one below the other A2:A6 and synamically generate the sheet formula using indirect referencing?

So if I just add the new tab sheet name in MASTER the formula results are auto updated.

A2:A32 contains the list of sheetnames

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("{",TEXTJOIN(";",true,ARRAYFORMULA("'" &A2:A32 &"'!" & "A2:B")),"}"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, `INDIRECT` doesn't work with `ArrayFormula`, sadly (I wish). But secondly, what's so cumbersome about updating the formula you have? Just format it like this:

```
=UNIQUE({
Appliances!A2:B;
'Base, Trim & Crown'!A2:B;
'Bathroom Accessories'!A2:B;
'Bathroom plumbing'!A2:B;
Cabinetry!A2:B;
Carpet!A2:B;
Closets!A2:B;
'Entry Door'!A2:B;
'Exterior and Interior Stone'!A2:B;
'Exterior Lighting and Fans'!A2:B;
'Exterior Siding'!A2:B;Fireplaces!A2:B;
'Garage Doors'!A2:B;
Gutter!A2:B;'Interior Door'!A2:B;
'Kitchen Plumbing'!A2:B;
'Paint Color'!A2:B;
'Patio Stone'!A2:B;
Roofing!A2:B;
Slab!A2:B;
Staircase!A2:B;
Tile!A2:B;
'Timbers, Beams & Ceilings'!A2:B;
'Windows & Multislides'!A2:B;
'Wood Flooring'!A2:B
})
```

Just add it where you want on the above list, leaving out the semicolon on the last item. (I'm not sure if you meant double quotes or not, so I left it as is.)

Or, if you really want to generate the sheet names from a list, you can use this, based on your above formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(
    ";"&CHAR(10),
    1,
    "'"&SORT(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)))&"'!A2:B"
))
```

which sorts in alphabetical order too. This outputs something you can copy+paste into your first formula.